# Joomla - Ajax content with email address in content is automatically converted to link and breaks page

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

I have build a full ajax website in joomla, but i am having a problem whenever i insert an email address in the content.

The email address is automatically converted to a hyperlink, therefore breaking the page completely when loaded with no css, just a white background with a email address hyperlinked.

Even if there was a hyperlinked email address, why would they break a ajax loaded page?

```
function getTheAjax(loadUrl){

                $("#ajax_p .container ").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl); 

            }
```

ajax_load is an html for an image

Comment: this comment is written in the return code

This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the joomla email cloaking plugin, and voila, all fixed